# Does $\mathbb{E}[Y|X,Z] = \mathbb{E}[Y|Z]$ almost surely imply $Y \perp X | Z$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

It is clear that $Y \perp X | Z \implies \mathbb{E}[Y|X,Z] = \mathbb{E}[Y|Z]$ almost surely,but does the reverse implication always hold?

Comment: Indeed, I object but also provide the "obvious" clarification that the statement is meant to be that $E[f(Y) g(X) | Z] = E[f(Y) | Z] E[g(X)| Z]$ for all $f,g$ bounded measurable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the other answer mentions, the condition does not suffice. However, if you assume $E[f(Y)|X,Z] = E[f(Y)|Z]$ for all bounded measurable $f$, that does suffice.

Write for any bounded measurable $f,g$ that $$
E[f(Y)g(X) | Z] = E[E[f(Y)g(X)| X, Z]|Z] = E[g(X) E[f(Y)|X,Z]|Z]
$$
$$
= E[g(X) E[f(Y)|Z] | Z]
= E[g(X) | Z] E[f(Y)|Z].
$$
Thus we have $Y\perp X$ conditional on $Z$.

Comment: Isn't that the definition of indepenence?

Answer (score 3):

No.

$\mathbb{E}[Y\mid X] = \mathbb{E}[Y]$ does not imply $Y \perp X $

so conditioning on $Z$ is just as unsatisfactory

Consider the following equally likely sets of values each with probability $\frac18$

```
X   Y   Z
1   1   3
1   5   3
2   2   3
2   4   3
1   3   5
1   7   5
2   4   5
2   6   5
```

You find $\mathbb{E}[Y\mid X,Z] = Z = \mathbb{E}[Y\mid Z]$, but $X$ determines the parity of $Y$ so they are not independent in any sense, conditional or otherwise